# button or label not working

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

When I try to change the text of a label on button click, the code compiles but it doesn't work. I click the button and nothing happens.
Currently, im just trying to display "Error" on label x1Label when button solveButton will be pressed. Could you please help me fixing it?

.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize errorLabel;
@synthesize aField, bField, cField;
@synthesize x1Label, x2Label;
@synthesize solveButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    aField.delegate = self;
    bField.delegate = self;
    cField.delegate = self;

    aField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    bField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    cField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

    NSString *str = @"car";
    errorLabel.text = str;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [aField resignFirstResponder];
    [bField resignFirstResponder];
    [cField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [aField resignFirstResponder];
    [bField resignFirstResponder];
    [cField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)solveButton:(id)sender
{
    errorLabel.text = @"Error";
}

@end
```

.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *aField, *bField, *cField;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *errorLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *aField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *x1Label;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *x2Label;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *solveButton;

@end
```

Thank you

Comment: write down self in front of every object like this :- "self.aField"

Comment: Check your IBOutlet properly and try out with self.errorLabel.text=@"error";

Comment: where should I write the self.aField.. and what should it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are writing on errorLabel not on x1Label.
2. Did you connect the SolveButton action to the button in your storyboard?
   if not go to storyboard > click on your button > go to Connection Inspector (on the right panel) and link the action to you button.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. It doesn't really matter if it goes to error label or x1 label as I just want to get it to work. Also, I cant seem to find connection inspector on my right panel.I however do have my button in referencing outlets connected to "view controller"

Comment: You need to connect the action to your button otherwise he does not know when you want the action to be done. The connection Inspector is in the up-right panel that you see when you click on your storyboard. There are many icons the one you are looking for is the arrow pointing outside your screen (the last one on the right). If you still can't find it google it and see the images :)

Comment: If your SolveButton is connect to the button you mean to press it's good! still doesn't work? If so there must be some error in the code i'll check it.

Comment: try this:  self.errorLabel.text = @"Error"; or _errorLabel.text = @"Error";

Comment: Thank you guys very much. What I did thanks to your help was that I opened the storyboard as ObiWanKeNerd suggested and I dragged an arrow from the button to my .a (IBAction) code. Now it works. Thanks!!! (Can't answer my own question due to being new user)